# Perl Regex to get a substring between two of the same characters

Tags: regex, string, perl, substring

Given some string `originalString = "#SomeWord# More words"`, I want to be able to get the substring `"SomeWord"` from the `originalString`.

Comment: so you just want the string that is bounded by hash marks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/#([^#]+)#/` works for me.

Some syntax notes:

- `//` delimiter characters marking the start and end of the regexp
- `#` literal hash mark
- `[]` a character class

Explanation of the regexp above:

- `[^#]` any character that isn't a hash mark
- `[^#]+` one or more such characters
- `([^#]+)` a [capturing group](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Grouping-things-and-hierarchical-matching) of the above

In this case, the regexp looks for any non-# characters between two #'s. Here's a full example:

```
my $foo = "#SomeWord# More words";

if ($foo =~ /#([^#]+)#/) {
    print "$1\n";
} else {
    print "no match\n";
}
```

Comment: Note that this regexp will not catch `##`, but this may be intended behavior.

Answer (score 3):

```
my $substr = (split /#/, $originalString)[1];
```

Comment: False alarm. On closer inspection it turns out I'd fallen foul of Perl associativity rules. I had `print (split /#/, $originalString)[1];`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use regular expressions:

```
$originalString=~ /\#([^#]+)\#/;
# Now $1 holds your required string
```